# Invalid cast from 'system.dbnull' error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am getting a system.dbnull error on my update from the code below.  Some of the values are null in the database and will return null on update.  I believe I am supposed to set the default value to equal null so it will stop returning the dbnull error, but I am unsure how / where to do this.

```
const string sql =
    @"UPDATE DoctorFacility SET PVId = @PVId, 
                                Type = @Type,
                                Inactive = @Inactive, 
                                Prefix = @Prefix,
                                First = @First,
                                Middle = @Middle,
                                Last = @Last,
                                Suffix = @Suffix,
                                OrgName = @OrgName,
                                OrgType = @OrgType, 
                                ListName = @ListName, 
                                Address1 = @Address1, 
                                Address2 = @Address2, 
                                City = @City, 
                                State = @State, 
                                Zip = @Zip, 
                                Country = @Country, 
                                Phone1 = @Phone1, 
                                Phone1Type = @Phone1Type, 
                                Phone2 = @Phone2, 
                                Phone2Type = @Phone2Type, 
                                EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, 
                                PlaceOfServiceMId = @PlaceOfSErviceMId, 
                                UPIN = @Upin, 
                                SpecialtyMId = @SpecialtyMId, 
                                DotId = @DotId, 
                                NPI = @NPI, 
                                CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
                                LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy 
        WHERE DotId = @DotId";
 using (SqlDataAccessor dataAccessor = DataAccessorFactory.GetDataAccessor(Connection))
 {
    string user = UserNameFactory.GetUsername();
    DaParameters parameters = new DaParameters(dataAccessor);
    parameters.Add("@PVId", DateTimeHash(DateTime.Now));
    parameters.Add("@Type", (int)provider.ProviderType);
    parameters.Add("@Inactive", provider.Inactive);
    parameters.Add("@Prefix", provider.Prefix, DbType.AnsiString, 10);
    parameters.Add("@First", provider.FirstName, DbType.AnsiString, 35);
    parameters.Add("@Middle", provider.MiddleName, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
    parameters.Add("@Last", provider.LastName, DbType.AnsiString, 60);
    parameters.Add("@Suffix", provider.Suffix, DbType.AnsiString, 20);
    parameters.Add("@OrgName", provider.OrgName, DbType.AnsiString, 60);
    parameters.Add("@OrgType", provider.OrgType, DbType.AnsiString, 3);
    parameters.Add("@ListName", provider.ListName, DbType.AnsiString, 160);
    parameters.Add("@Address1", provider.Address1, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
    parameters.Add("@Address2", provider.Address2, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
    parameters.Add("@City", provider.City, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
    parameters.Add("@State", provider.State, DbType.AnsiString, 3);
    parameters.Add("@Zip", provider.Zip, DbType.AnsiString, 10);
    parameters.Add("@Country", provider.Country, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
    parameters.Add("@Phone1", provider.Phone1, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
    parameters.Add("@Phone1Type", provider.Phone1Type, DbType.AnsiString, 25);
    parameters.Add("@Phone2", provider.Phone2, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
    parameters.Add("@Phone2Type", provider.Phone2Type, DbType.AnsiString, 25);
    parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", provider.EmailAddress, DbType.AnsiString, 255);
    parameters.Add("@PlaceOfServiceMId", provider.PlaceOfServiceMID);
    parameters.Add("@UPIN", provider.UPIN, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
    parameters.Add("@SpecialtyMId", provider.SpecialtyMID);
    parameters.Add("@DotId", provider.DotID, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
    parameters.Add("@NPI", provider.NPI, DbType.AnsiString, 80);
    parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", user, DbType.AnsiString);
    parameters.Add("@LastModifiedBy", user, DbType.AnsiString);
    return dataAccessor.ExecuteIdentityInsert<Provider>(sql, parameters);
 }
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the exact wording of the error you get? It's unclear to me what would be wrong with this at first glance.

I am curious why you are using a command called `ExecuteIdentityInsert` to perform an update. Perhaps you have the wrong method on your `dataAccessor`? The method name would imply that it's for inserting a `Provider` to the database with an explicit identity value.

Comment: Please provide full exception message which is coming. and there is very good thing in IDEs now a days - **debugger**

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. I'm happy to help if my answer did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this is running on ADO.NET, it doesn't know how to translate .NET nulls to SQL Server nulls.

Try null-coalescing any suspected null inputs to DBNull.Value in the System namespace, like so:

`parameters.Add("@First", provider.FirstName ?? DBNull.Value, DbType.AnsiString, 35);`